# How do I prevent Night Shift from being disabled when switching on Inverted Colors on macOS?

Tags: macos, night-shift, accessibility

When Night Shift is turned on on my iPhone and I toggle Inverted Colors on and off, mode Night Shift is still enabled. When I does the same on my Mac Night Shift is disabled. It looks like it is disabled as soon as I turn Inverted Colors on. Also toggling Inverted Colors disables the Night Shift schedule. How do I prevent this from happening?